# Distribute heavyweight tasks evenly between nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a MapReduce job that consists of a single input file containing several lines of records. Each record took a **fair amount of time** to be processed. Therefore, my input file, although its size may be **far less than HDFS block size**, will take a significant amount of time when it is executed on a single node.

How to tell Hadoop to efficiently split the input file evenly between the nodes? Such that even though the input file is small, it is still split into several tasks to be executed in parallel.

Also, can we tell hadoop to split the file into exactly N tasks, where N is the number of available nodes?

Thank you!

Edit:
For more clarity, what I want to do is something like the following. I have many large files. I have an external program which will process each of the files. Each file takes large amount of time to be processed.

So, I store the filenames of the files in an input file, then I want Hadoop to split it evenly. Then in the mapper I copied the files corresponding to the IDs to local machine and call the program.

Answer (score 0):

How much was this `fair amount of time`?Looks like you have misunderstood Hadoop. There will be some initial delay when you launch a MR job. This is a `must` and `unavoidable`, whether your data is 1KB or 1TB. This delay is incurred because of stuff like initialization, splitting, map creation etc etc. It is not because your file has several records. And processing files of size `far less than HDFS block size` is not gonna give you any plus. To be frank it is inefficient use of Hadoop.

You don't have to tell Hadoop anything. The platform is smart enough to split the file for maximum efficiency. If you have a file, smaller than block, and you are still splitting it then you will further reduce performance.

You can tell Hadoop to split a file into  `N` parts but it is not straightforward. You have to extend the API and write your own custom `InputFormat` to achieve this, since splitting the input is the duty of InputFormat.

But before doing any of this, I would suggest you to read some more about Hadoop. Also, please go through this post :
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/

---

In response to your last comment :

If I have understood it correctly, you are using MR to split the file that holds the "input filenames" and to copy that file to your local FS. Are you really getting any major advantage with this approach?I mean MR shows its power when used with a distributed store like HDFS. Moreover when you copy that large file using MR you'll loose data ordering and might end up getting wrong results. IMHO, you are better off keeping those files in your local FS itself and splitting the file containing names using a simple Java program. I don't see any point in using Hadoop `just as a store`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Each record **will take** a fair amount of time to be processed". So basically each record is an ID of "something" that is stored somewhere else, and it will take much time to process that "thing". I want to process all "thing"s in parallel efficiently, hence the question.

Comment: So you can aggregate that "something" with its IDs and store them on HDFS, that will give you a bigger file and Hadoop knows how to handle big files

Comment: I agree with @darkjh. But, just to get myself clear, why are you worried about "record(ID)" when your actual goal is to process the "something" associated with this record(ID)?

Comment: Yes, I store the "something" in HDFS already. But, when the mapper processes an ID, it will copy the thing out from HDFS to local machine because it will be processed by an external program (not by the mapper or reducer), which cannot read HDFS.

Comment: For more clarity, I have added small explanation in the question.

Comment: @fushar : I'm sorry for the late response. Please see the edited answer(can't write that much here) and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You may set number of mapper and reducer tasks for your job like below

```
    conf.setNumMapTasks(10);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(5);
```

You may also change the Input split size according to your needs using `mapred.max.split.size` property.

Comment: Thank you, I adjust `mapred.max.split.size` as suggested.